# Spring cloud stream not recover channel on timed out error

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I know it uses spring-amqp to handle recovery. One case I found where it doesn't recover the channel is that if a spring cloud stream app couldn't process message within 30 mins (default timeout for a message not being acked), the rabbitmq will close the channel with error

```
channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more, class-id=0, method-id=0)
```

While the app is processing the message, the message will be in unacked state in rabbitmq. There is a 30 mins timeout, exceeding which the rabbitmq will close channel and consumer and put the message back to the queue. In the end the app will print out such error message in the log and do nothing. How do I make it recover in this case?